# Deploying phoenix with edeliver fails at migrate

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

When I run `mix edeliver migrate production` I get this error:

```
production node:

  user    : deploy
  host    : myIP
  path    : /home/deploy
  response: RPC to 'bot@127.0.0.1' failed: {'EXIT',
                                {#{'__exception__' => true,
                                   '__struct__' =>
                                    'Elixir.DBConnection.ConnectionError',
                                   message =>
                                    <<"connection not available because of disconnection">>},
                                 [{'Elixir.DBConnection',checkout,2,
                                   [{file,"lib/db_connection.ex"},{line,926}]},
                                  {'Elixir.DBConnection',run,3,
                                   [{file,"lib/db_connection.ex"},{line,742}]},
                                  {'Elixir.DBConnection',run_meter,3,
                                   [{file,"lib/db_connection.ex"},
                                    {line,1133}]},
                                  {'Elixir.DBConnection',prepare_execute,4,
                                   [{file,"lib/db_connection.ex"},{line,584}]},
                                  {'Elixir.Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection',
                                   execute,4,
                                   [{file,
                                     "lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex"},
                                    {line,86}]},
                                  {'Elixir.Ecto.Adapters.SQL',sql_call,6,
                                   [{file,"lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex"},
                                    {line,256}]},
                                  {'Elixir.Ecto.Adapters.SQL','query!',5,
                                   [{file,"lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex"},
                                    {line,198}]},
                                  {'Elixir.Ecto.Adapters.Postgres',
                                   '-execute_ddl/3-fun-0-',4,
                                   [{file,"lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex"},
                                    {line,85}]}]}}
```

I did remote_console and `Application.get_all_env(:example)` to check DB details and they are correct. I am deploying another phoenix application on the same server and database works.

I tried changing pool size on both applications, didn't help.

I think I probably did something small wrong but can't pinpoint due to wired error.

Comment: Does your database user have a password? https://github.com/edeliver/edeliver/issues/113 was resolved by adding a password to the database user. The error message is identical to yours.

Comment: Yes, I looked at this issue - It has both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so over a year later and I still keep running into these vague message migration errors when deploying with edeliver/distilery.

I found the best solution to be enabling remote DB access and modifying `dev.exs` config to temporarily use production DB. Then running `mix ecto.migrate` shows the actual error, which in my current case was:

`permission denied to create extension "pg_trgm"`